Users cant authenticate to AZ using ConnectToAzure
I have a PowerShell script which logs into Az.  Using PS 7.2.4, AZ Module 12. Tested on Win 10 and 11.
The script uses AZconnect to access Azure and grab some information.  It works fine on my PC. However, when other users run the script on their PCs, it doesnt actually log them in, so when it runs a AZ command it gives the error:
"Get-AzVM: Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to set up your Azure credentials.Authentication failed against tenant . User interaction is required. This may be due to the conditional access policy settings such as multi-factor authentication (MFA). If you need to access subscriptions in that tenant, please rerun 'Connect-AzAccount' with additional parameter '-TenantId '."
The script uses the following code
$USER = 'AnAccount@atenant.onmicrosoft.com'
$PWORD = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force 
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($USER, $PWORD)
Connect-AzAccount -TenantID '<ID here>' -subscription <SubID here> -Credential $Credential 

To de-bug, I've run those lines line by line, and it works fine on my PC but on other users PCs the Connect-AzAccount doesn't log in. The warning they get is:
WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant '' with error 'Authentication failed against tenant . User interaction is required. This may be due to the conditional access policy settings such as multi-factor authentication (MFA). If you need to access subscriptions in that tenant, please rerun 'Connect-AzAccount' with additional parameter '-TenantId <tenantID'.
I'm running in Admin mode on users PCs and also setting execution-policy.  When I run Az-context, it lists the correct account,Tenant and subscription. The account does not use MFA and its not yet using Conditional Access Policy.
Its not a permissions thing on the account being used as the script works fine when I run it.
I appreciate its not the most secure method, but I'd rather not change from this log-in method (it works for me, the script is private and the account is basic).
Can anyone explain why it works on my PC but not others and how to fix it.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Some systems may still be using Windows Credentials and others may have moved to OAUTH2.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/architecture/auth-oauth2

All the machines are in the same tenant, and they are using the same credentials as me. Is this change machine specific? How could I fix it?  Thanks!

Did you run Connect-AzAccount?

just on its own?  It will ask for interactive credentials (it requests  a set of credentials to use, then when you click on it, it hangs)

Di you rerun with 'Connect-AzAccount' with additional parameter '-TenantId

Yep, good question but as you can see in my code I already use that parameter

It turns out that MS has somehow messed up the Az-Connect login process.  See
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/24967
